# What does the minimum x that satify $x=24n+12=15m+6=11k+2$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My attempt so far was: let $x=24n+12=15m+6=11k+2$ 
find $x$ as the form $x=24*15*a+24*11*b+15*11*c$
$$2\equiv 24\cdot 15\cdot a\quad (mod\quad 11)\quad \Rightarrow 1\equiv 4\cdot a\Rightarrow \quad a=3\\ 6\equiv 24\cdot 11\cdot b\quad (mod\quad 15)\quad \Rightarrow \quad 2\equiv 8\cdot 11\cdot b\quad (mod\quad 5)\quad \Rightarrow 2\equiv 3\cdot b\quad (mod\quad 5)\quad \quad $$ and I stack here after finding $a$

Comment: Are  $m,n,k$ positive integers?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1,yes they are

Comment: $15m-24n=6$, $11k-24n=10$, $11k-15m=4$. So Diophantine equation is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\!x\equiv 12\pmod{\!24}\!\iff x/3\,\equiv\ \ \  4\,\pmod{\! 8}$
$\!\!\left.\begin{align} 
&x\equiv \  6\!\!\pmod{\!15}\!\iff x/3\,\equiv\ \ \  2\!\!\!\pmod{ 5}\\ 
&x\equiv \  2\!\!\pmod{\!11}\!\iff x/3\,\equiv -3\!\!\!\pmod{\!\!11}\\
\end{align}\right\}\!\!\!\iff\!\dfrac{x}3\equiv -3\pmod{\!55}\!\iff\! \dfrac{x}3 = \color{#0a0}{-3\!+\!55j}$

$\!\!\!\bmod \color{#c00}8\!:\, 4\equiv \dfrac{x}3\equiv \color{#0a0}{-3\!+\!55}\color{#c00}j\equiv 5\!-\!j\!\!\iff\! \color{#c00}{j\equiv 1}\!\iff\! \dfrac{x}3=-3\!+\!55(\color{#c00}{1\!+\!8i})\!\iff\!\! x\equiv 156\!+\!1320i $

Comment: $\bmod 11\!:\,\ \dfrac{x}3 \equiv \overbrace{\dfrac{2}3\equiv \dfrac{-9}3}^{\Large 2 \ \ \equiv\ \ -9}\equiv -3,\ \,$ and $\,\ 2\equiv -3\pmod{\!5}\,\ $ [for completeness]

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
   24n + 12 &= 15m + 6 \\
   8n + 4 &= 5m + 2 \\
   5m - 8n &= 2 \\
\end{align}

Since $10-8=2$ we see that $(m,n)=(2,1)$ is a particular solution. So, in general
$(m,n) = (2+8t, 1+5t)$.

Then
\begin{align}
   15m + 6 &= 11k + 2 \\
   15(2+8t) + 6 &= 11k + 2 \\
   120t + 36 &= 11k + 2 \\
   11k - 120t &= 34 \\
\end{align}

Noting that $120+34 = 154 = 14 \times 11$, we see that $(k,t) = (14,2)$ is a particular solution. So, in general, $(k, t) = (14+120u, 2+11u)$.

So, in general,
$$\begin{array}{l}
   m = 2+8t = 88u + 18 \\
   n = 1+5t = 55u + 11 \\
   k = 120u + 14
\end{array}$$

We then find that
$$\begin{array}{l}
   x = 24n + 12 = 1320 u + 276 \\
   x = 15m + 6 = 1320 u + 276 \\
   x = 11k + 2 = 1320 u + 156
\end{array}$$

The smallest positive value of $x$ is $1320$.

If you want to use congruences, then

\begin{align}\
   x = 24n + 12 &\iff x \equiv 12 \pmod{24} 
                &\iff \left\{\begin{array}{l}
                         x \equiv 4 \pmod 8 \\
                         x \equiv 0 \pmod 3
                       \end{array} \right.\\
   x = 15m + 6  &\iff x \equiv 6 \pmod{15}
                &\iff \left\{\begin{array}{l}
                         x \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
                         x \equiv 0 \pmod 3
                       \end{array} \right.\\
   x = 11k + 2  &&\iff x \equiv 2 \pmod{11}
\end{align}

Which simplifies to

\begin{align}\
   x &\equiv 4 \pmod{8} \\
   x &\equiv 1 \pmod{5} \\
   x &\equiv 0 \pmod{3} \\
   x &\equiv 2 \pmod{11}
\end{align}

We find $N = 8\times 5\times 3 \times 11 = 1320$; so 
$\dfrac N8 = 165, \dfrac N5 = 264, \dfrac N3 = 440$,
and $\dfrac{N}{11} = 120$. We compute

\begin{array}{r|cccc|l} 
    & \pmod 8 & \pmod 5 & \pmod 3 & \pmod{11}\\
\hline
   165 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   264 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
   440 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
   120 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\hline
    660 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 &5\times 4 \equiv 4 \pmod 8\\
   -264 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &4\times -1 \equiv 1 \pmod 5\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &2\times 0 \equiv 0 \pmod 3\\
   -240 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 &-2\times -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{11}\\
\hline
\end{array}

Adding, we get $x \equiv 660-264+0-240 \equiv 156 \pmod{1320}$

Comment: It can be done more simply with a couple optimizations - see my answer.